# Young tableau in subscript

Tags: subscripts, ytableau, youngtab

I am using the `youngtab` package to generate Young diagrams and Young tableaux. The issue I want to ask about is a cosmetic one. When using a tableau as a subscript, as in `$X_{\young(k)}$` for example, the size of the tableau does not adjust, as other symbols would. How might one force a subscript sized tableau?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obliquely addressed in section 2.2 of the `youngtab` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}
\begin{document}
\young(k) {\scriptsize\young(k)}

$X_{\mbox{\scriptsize\young(k)}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!